# How to post Java String to java entryPoint method with CCharPointer type using GraalVM?

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to create a shared library(so with header and lib files) of a java code using graalvm.

There will be one java method with 2 parameters of type String which I will call from Java

**My NativeNativeImpl java method analysis with annotation CEntryPoint looks like this**:

```
@CEntryPoint(name = "Java_net_luculent_liems_license_apinative_Native_analysis")
public static CCharPointer analysis(Pointer jniEnv, Pointer clazz,
                               @CEntryPoint.IsolateThreadContext long isolateId, CCharPointer dataCharStr) {
    //logic code
}
```

My Native java code to call analysis looks like this :

```
//declare native method 
private static native String analysis(long isolateThread, CCharPointer dataDomStr);

public static String analysisDataDom() {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeimpl");
        long isolateThread = createIsolate();
        String helloStr = "Hello from Java";
        //how to convert helloStr to CCharPointer type ???
        return analysis(isolateThread, helloStr);
}
```

My question likes comment: **how to post java String value to CCharPointer for native method?**

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTypeConversion (from `import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CTypeConversion`) to turn it into a holder and holder.get() will return a CCharPointer.

```
final CTypeConversion.CCharPointerHolder holder=CTypeConversion.toCString(result);
            return holder.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create an interface for your JNI env:

```
import com.oracle.svm.jni.nativeapi.JNIHeaderDirectives;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.IsolateThread;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.CContext;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function.CEntryPoint;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function.CFunctionPointer;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function.InvokeCFunctionPointer;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.struct.CField;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.struct.CStruct;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CCharPointer;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CTypeConversion;
import org.graalvm.word.Pointer;
import org.graalvm.word.PointerBase;

@CContext(JNIHeaderDirectives.class)
@CStruct(value = "JNIEnv_", addStructKeyword = true)
interface JNIEnv extends PointerBase {

    @CField("functions")
    JNINativeInterface getFunctions();

    @CStruct(value = "JNINativeInterface_", addStructKeyword = true)
    interface JNINativeInterface extends PointerBase {
        @CField
        NewStringUTF getNewStringUTF();

        @CField
        GetStringUTFChars getGetStringUTFChars();
    }

    interface JObject extends PointerBase {
    }

    interface JString extends JObject {
    }

    interface NewStringUTF extends CFunctionPointer {
        @InvokeCFunctionPointer
        JString call(JNIEnv env, CCharPointer cCharPointer);
    }

    interface GetStringUTFChars extends CFunctionPointer {
        @InvokeCFunctionPointer
        CCharPointer call(JNIEnv env, JString str, byte isCopy);
    }
}

public class Analysis {
    @CEntryPoint(name = "Java_net_luculent_liems_license_apinative_Native_analysis")
    public static void analysis(JNIEnv jniEnv, Pointer clazz, @CEntryPoint.IsolateThreadContext long isolateId, JNIEnv.JString dataCharStr) {
        JNIEnv.JNINativeInterface fn = jniEnv.getFunctions();
        CCharPointer charptr = fn.getGetStringUTFChars().call(jniEnv, dataCharStr, (byte) 0);
        final String resultString  =  CTypeConversion.toJavaString(charptr);
        System.out.println(resultString);
    }

    @CEntryPoint(name = "Java_net_luculent_liems_license_apinative_Native_createIsolate", builtin=CEntryPoint.Builtin.CREATE_ISOLATE)
    public static native IsolateThread createIsolate();
}
```

And from your Java application you can declare the native method as:

```
    private static native void analysis(long isolateThread, String dataDomStr);
```

Comment: This is causing heap memory issue at below line
CCharPointer charptr = fn.getGetStringUTFChars().call(jniEnv, dataCharStr, (byte) 0);

How to free this CCharPointer